# WSO2 Basic Authentication and url redirect

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an API which I would like to secure. I have followed the [Example](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/09/get-cup-coffee-wso2-way/). The API is secured, but the request does not get forwarded to the API and I dont see the response from the API. 
The API has some dynamic URI variables which get set. If I hard code the uri-template then the API works, but if I dont it just hangs!

## JAVA CLASS

```
package com.pru.basicauth.handler.rest;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender;
import org.apache.synapse.rest.Handler;

public class BasicAuthHandler1 implements Handler {
    public void addProperty(String s, Object o) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public Map getProperties() {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {

        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext
                = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
        Object headers = axis2MessageContext.getProperty(
                org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);


        if (headers != null && headers instanceof Map) {
            Map headersMap = (Map) headers;
            if (headersMap.get("Authorization") == null) {
                headersMap.clear();
                axis2MessageContext.setProperty("HTTP_SC", "401");
                headersMap.put("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"WSO2 ESB\"");
                axis2MessageContext.setProperty("NO_ENTITY_BODY", new Boolean("true"));
                messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE", "true");
                messageContext.setTo(null);
                Axis2Sender.sendBack(messageContext);
                return false;

            } else {
                String authHeader = (String) headersMap.get("Authorization");
                String credentials = authHeader.substring(6).trim();
                if (processSecurity(credentials)) {
                    **headersMap.clear(); //This worked for me!**
                    return true;
                } else {
                    headersMap.clear();
                    axis2MessageContext.setProperty("HTTP_SC", "403");
                    axis2MessageContext.setProperty("NO_ENTITY_BODY", new Boolean("true"));
                    messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE", "true");
                    messageContext.setTo(null);
                    Axis2Sender.sendBack(messageContext);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean processSecurity(String credentials) {
        String decodedCredentials = new String(new Base64().decode(credentials.getBytes()));
        String userName = decodedCredentials.split(":")[0];
        String password = decodedCredentials.split(":")[1];
        if ("admin".equals(userName) && "admin".equals(password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

## API THAT WORKS!

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TApi" context="/ta">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/city" protocol="https" outSequence="conf:/taOut">
      <inSequence>
         <sequence key="conf:/taConf"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http trace="enable" method="GET" uri-template="http://abcd:1234/html/en/default/rest/Integration?USERNAME=XXXXXX&amp;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx&amp;ioName=Geography%20-%20Database%20-%20Create%20City%20Inbound"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

## API THAT DOES NOT WORK

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TApi" context="/ta">
           <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/city" protocol="https" outSequence="conf:/taOut">
              <inSequence>
                 <sequence key="conf:/taConf"/>
                 <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
                 <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
                 <send>
                    <endpoint>
                       <http trace="enable" method="GET" uri-template="{uri.var.service.host}:{uri.var.service.port}/html/en/default/rest/Integration?USERNAME={uri.var.service.user}&amp;PASSWORD={uri.var.service.pass}&amp;ioName=Geography%20-%20Database%20-%20Create%20City%20Inbound"/>
                    </endpoint>
                 </send>
              </inSequence>
              <faultSequence/>
           </resource>
        </api>
```

## taConf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="conf:taConf">
   <property name="uri.var.service.user"
             value="XXXXX"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property name="uri.var.service.pass"
             value="XXXXXXXX"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property name="uri.var.service.host"
             value="XXXXXXX"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property name="uri.var.service.port"
             value="XXXXX"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
</sequence>
```

## taOut

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="conf:taOut"
          trace="enable">
   <out>
      <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')"
              regex="^(2[0-9][0-9])$">
         <then>
            <payloadFactory media-type="text">
               <format>RetCode=C;Message=Success</format>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send/>
         </then>
         <else>
            <payloadFactory media-type="text">
               <format>RetCode=F;Message=Failed because Itegration Exception</format>
            </payloadFactory>
         </else>
      </filter>
   </out>
</sequence>
```

## HTTP Logs

```
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,020] DEBUG - wire >> "GET /t/city HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,021] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 48.123.84.5:8243[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,021] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,021] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,021] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,022] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,024] DEBUG - wire << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,024] DEBUG - wire << "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WSO2 ESB"[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,024] DEBUG - wire << "Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 13:20:52 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,024] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,025] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,025] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,025] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,025] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,048] DEBUG - wire >> "G"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,049] DEBUG - wire >> "ET /tririga/city HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,049] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 48.123.84.5:8243[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,050] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,050] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,050] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,051] DEBUG - wire >> "Authorization: Basic YWaaaa6YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,051] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,055]  INFO - LogMediator host = localhost, port = 1234, user = XXXXXX, pass = XXXXXX
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,065] DEBUG - wire << "GET http://localhost:1234/aaaa?USERNAME=XXXXXX&PASSWORD=XXXXXX&ioName=Geogra
phy%20-%20Database%20-%20Create%20City%20Inbound HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,065] DEBUG - wire << "Authorization: Basic YWRtaaaaaaRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,066] DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,066] DEBUG - wire << "Host: localhost:1234[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,066] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,066] DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,066] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,076] DEBUG - wire >> "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,076] DEBUG - wire >> "Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 13:20:51 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,077] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 13[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,077] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,077] DEBUG - wire >> "WWW-Authenticate: Basic[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,077] DEBUG - wire >> "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8p3JLQcWIB7Y97_t6gSnVCJ2zze328m0-vRF1-QajTGg3pn5T-Fj!1643223368; path=/[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,077] DEBUG - wire >> "X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,078] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-05-19 09:20:52,078] DEBUG - wire >> "Login Failed."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have already tested mentioned scenario with the WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and it's working for me(refer blog post [1]). Can you check the values of the URI variables again.
You can add log mediator before to the send mediator in the API configuration.

```
<log level="custom" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="host"
              expression="get-property('uri.var.service.user')"/>
</log>
<log level="custom" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="host"
              expression="get-property('uri.var.service.pass')"/>
</log>
<log level="custom" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="host"
              expression="get-property('uri.var.service.host')"/>
</log>
<log level="custom" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="host"
              expression="get-property('uri.var.service.port')"/>
</log>
```

Also you can enable the wire logs in ESB and then you can see the full endpoint URL in the carbon logs.
You can use below steps to enable the wirelogs in ESB.

1) open the "log4j.properties" file located in ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory.
2) uncommnet the below line and save the file.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

3) start the ESB server.

After enable the wire logs, you can invoke the API and in the carbon logs, you can see the values of the URI variables and complete endpoint URL.
Then you can compare those values with,

[1]- https://susankhanirmala.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/how-to-appending-a-context-and-query-string-parameters-to-the-target-rest-endpoint-using-wso2-esb/

Comment: Thank you for you response, I have tried this without the handler and it works fine. But when I add the handler it does not seem to be working at all. Initially, it send the request without the Authorization header, and then it gets the header with the Authorization: Basic sadashdlas= which gets decoded and checked. It passes and returns true. Still I keep getting unauthorized 403 (Login Failed).

Comment: Finally it worked for me by making the following changes to the java class. I cleared the header before sending it to the api. That pretty much did it for me.